# I want all pages access to 'SplitViewRoot' except for 'LoginPage' in UWP, how to make it work?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am a beginner working on a uwp project and I created a 'SplitViewRootControl' which is something like this:

```
    <Grid>
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Background.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <SplitView x:Name="SplitViewRootControl" Grid.Row="1" DisplayMode="CompactInline"  OpenPaneLength="150" CompactPaneLength="0" PaneBackground="Black" Opacity=".8">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <RelativePanel>
                        <Image x:Name="userIcon" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/user.png" Width="35" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" Margin="10,20,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="user" RelativePanel.RightOf="userIcon" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="userIcon" RelativePanel.AlignTopWith="userIcon" Text="User:" FontSize="13" Margin="5,18,0,0" Foreground="Ivory" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="userName" RelativePanel.RightOf="userIcon" RelativePanel.Below="user" Text="Chen Yinjue" FontSize="13" Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="Ivory" />
                    </RelativePanel>

                    <GridView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/messenger.png" Width="70" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Messenger" FontSize="18" Foreground="Ivory" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,50"/>
                            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/warning.png" Width="70" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Alert" FontSize="18" Foreground="Ivory" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,50"/>
                            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/cctv.png" Width="70" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Camera Setup" FontSize="18" Foreground="Ivory" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,50"/>
                            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/more.png" Width="70" />
                            <TextBlock Text="More" FontSize="18" Foreground="Ivory" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </GridView>

                    <Button Grid.Row="2" 
                            Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=appButtonStyle}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Content="Log Out" 
                            FontSize="20" 
                            Foreground="White"
                            Background="#dd514c"/>
                </Grid>
            </SplitView.Pane>

            <SplitView.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Frame x:Name="rootFrame"/>
                    <Button Name="HamburgerBtn"
                            Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=appButtonStyle}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Background="Black"
                            Opacity=".4"
                            Click="HamburgerBtn_Click">
                        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/paneBtn.png" Height="300" Width="20"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And I managed to make all pages in the app access to this 'splitview' by overwrite 'OnLaunched' in app.xaml.cs:

```
    var rootControl = Window.Current.Content as SplitViewRoot;

        if (rootControl == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootControl = new SplitViewRoot();

            rootControl.RootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootControl;
        }

        if (rootControl.RootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootControl.RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(LoginPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        Window.Current.Activate();
```

The problem is there is a 'LoginPage' in the app and it should not have this 'splitview' in its page. So basically I want all my pages access to 'splitview' except for 'LoginPage'. Anybody knows how to do that? Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: What's `SplitViewRoot`? Did you mean all the pages in your project will contain `SplitViewRootControl`? Why you need this? Could you please tell about your demands on this project?

Comment: Hi, yes it means all the pages in my project will contaion 'SplitViewRootControl' except 'LoginPage'. 'SplitViewRootControl' aims to let user navigate among several basic functions in the app such as go to 'messenger' or go to 'camera set up' so I need it to show at each page except 'LoginPage'. In another word, user is able to access to 'SplitViewRootControl' at any time to navigate them among pages after they log in to the app. Hope I help to make it clearer, tks!